# add and update input value sequentially on click event in reactjs

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, reactjs

I am trying to write a function in reactjs where the input value will be updated sequentially in the given array onclick specific index  add button.
Its the sandbox link of what i have done so far:
https://codesandbox.io/s/sidename-8k2z3
This is state value as a json:

```
this.state ={
    locationSiteList:[ {
        "sideName": 'Ceiling',
        "length": "",
    },
        {
            "sideName": 'Floor',
            "length": "",
        },
        {
            "sideName": 'East wall',
            "length": "",
        }

    ],

};
```

What i want is  if click on add button on very first index then the sideName will be changed automatically to Ceiling1 and will add another array named ceiling 2.Again in case of floor index if i click on floor add button  it will be changed like floor1,floor2.The expected result will look something like this:

```
locationSiteList:[ {
                "sideName": 'Ceiling1',
                "length": "",
            },
                {
                    "sideName": 'Ceiling2',
                    "length": "",
                },

                {
                    "sideName": 'Floor1',
                    "length": "",
                },
                {
                    "sideName": 'Floor2',
                    "length": "",
                },
                {
                    "sideName": 'East wall',
                    "length": "",
                }

            ],
```

And this is in render i am mapping:

```
 <Grid item xs={12}>
                        {
                            this.state.locationSiteList.map((dev, key) =>
                                <Grid container style={{marginTop:'8px'}}>

                                    <Grid item xs={3}  style={{}}>
                                        <input disabled style={{width:'100%'}}
                                               type="text" value={dev.sideName}  />
                                    </Grid>


                                    <Grid item xs={1} style={{paddingLeft:'8px'}}>

                                            <input disabled style={{width:'100%'}}
                                                   type="text"  />
                                    </Grid>


                                    <button type="button" fullWidth="true" variant="contained"
                                            onClick={() => { this.insertSides()}}>
                                        Add
                                    </button>

                                </Grid>
                            )}

                    </Grid>
```

This is my add fuction:

```
   insertSides = () => {
        console.log('rawInsert....');
        const locationSiteList = [...this.state.locationSiteList];

        if (locationSiteList.length < 1) {
            var a = 1
        } else {
            var a = locationSiteList.length + 1
        }
        locationSiteList.push({
            'sideName': a,


        });

        this.setState({locationSiteList: locationSiteList});
    };
```

How can i make it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I spent sometime tweaking your existing code in the linked sandbox
I am not sure what is the purpose of "length" in the array objects, So I replaced that with an id to track things easy.

```
import React from "react";
import Grid from "@material-ui/core/Grid";
import "./App.css";

class ModalDemo extends React.Component {
  state = {
    showModal: false,
    caption: "",
    modalSrc: "",
    locationSiteList: [
      {
        sideName: "Ceiling",
        id: "C"
      },
      {
        sideName: "Floor",
        id: "F"
      },
      {
        sideName: "East wall",
        id: "EW"
      }
    ]

    // ...rest of the state
  };
  insertSides = (item) => {
    const locationSiteList = [...this.state.locationSiteList];
    var count = locationSiteList.filter((obj) => obj.id === item.id).length;

    var position = locationSiteList.indexOf(item);
    position = position + count;

    count = count + 1;

    locationSiteList.splice(position, 0, {
      sideName: item.sideName + count,
      id: item.id
    });

    this.setState({ locationSiteList: locationSiteList });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Grid item xs={12}>
          {this.state.locationSiteList.map((dev, key) => (
            <Grid container style={{ marginTop: "8px" }}>
              <Grid item xs={3} style={{}}>
                <input
                  disabled
                  style={{ width: "100%" }}
                  type="text"
                  value={dev.sideName}
                />
              </Grid>

              <Grid item xs={1} style={{ paddingLeft: "20px" }}>
                <input style={{ width: "100%" }} type="text" />
              </Grid>

              <button
                style={{ marginLeft: "20px" }}
                type="button"
                fullWidth="true"
                variant="contained"
                onClick={() => {
                  this.insertSides(dev);
                }}
              >
                Add
              </button>
            </Grid>
          ))}
        </Grid>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default ModalDemo;
```

This has an limitation if the user clicks on "Ceiling2" Add button it creates new item "Ceiling23".
To avoid this only allow the 3 initial buttons and hide the rest.

Comment: it works perfectly fine.Any way to make it  in order like ceiling 2  wont be shown in the last rather show it after ceiling1?

Comment: Updated the above code spinet to do the same. cheers